# Spring - IoC Container - How to use dynamic values in properties ? (like a concat of 2 Strings)

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring framework and I don't know how to do this simple thing:
I want to provide a String to a bean, with the string being the result of the concatenation of multiple part, some fixed and other variables

For example it could be something like: 
`"myReportFile_20102101_1832.txt"`
- the first part is a fixed part
- the second part is a timestamp with current date time
- the last part is another fixed part

How to achieve that using the simplest way ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like a Job for the [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (introduced in Spring 3.0) to me. Though it might be easier to use a [factory bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) for that task (it gets the static information injected via IOC and offers a factory method that instantiates your other bean including the calculated dynamic information). Like so

```
class FileNameFactoryBean
{
    private Date date = new Date();
    private String prefix;
    private String postfix;

    public OtherBean createBean()
    {
        String filename = prefix + date.toString() + postfix;
        return new OtherBean(filename);
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And then in your bean configuration something like

```
<bean id="fileNameFactory" class="package.FileNameFactoryBean">
    <property name="prefix" value="file_" />
    <property name="postfix" value=".txt" />
</bean>

<bean id="otherBean" factory-bean="fileNameFactory" factory-method="createBean"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the expression language more simple and natural, but as I'm with spring 2.5, I'll go with the Factory Bean.

Answer (score 3):

Use the MethodInvokingFactoryBean.  You can give it a static method on another class that takes a file name and appends a timestamp to it, or whatever other logic you might like to have.

See the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) for more info, and an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate that logic to an [init-method](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/bean-init.shtml)

```
<bean id="myBean" class="foo.MyBean" init-method="nameBuilder">
    <property name="pre" value="myReportFile_" />
    <property name="ext" value=".txt" />
</bean>
```

and then in your Bean Class

```
public class MyBean {
....
    public void nameBuilder() {
       setName(pre+System.currentTimeMillis()+ext); //or anything you want..
    }
}
```